# The "All actions", "Responses" and "Votes" tabs appears to be broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Anyone else experiencing an error when they click the "All actions" tab of their Activity page?

Apparently the "Responses" and "Votes" tabs are broken as well.

*Apparently it was intermittent/random, or it just got fixed.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Nick Craver, it's [been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328452/162102) and they have some more work to do to make it stay fixed.